# Module not found: Can't resolve '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-tong'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ckeditor, npm-install

I was trying to import the package that i download from online ckeditor builder. Am i doing it correctly? How should I import it?

1. npm install from the ckeditor folder.
2. npm build from the ckeditor folder.

editor.jsx

```
import React, { Component, Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import Editor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-tong';

const TEditor = ({onEditorStateChange, defaultValue}) => {
    const onChange = (event, editor ) => {
      const data = editor.getData();
      console.log(  data  );
      onEditorStateChange(data)
    };

    const onBlur = (event, editor) => {
      console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
    };

    const onFocus = (event, editor) => {
      console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
    };

    const onInit = (editor) => {
      console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
    };

    const editorConfiguration = {
    };

    return (
        <div className="editor">
            {/* <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2> */}
            <CKEditor
                editor={Editor}
                config={editorConfiguration}
                data={defaultValue ? defaultValue : ""}
                onInit={onInit}
                onChange={onChange}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onFocus={onFocus}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default TEditor;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tws-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://www.google.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^21.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-tong": "file:./src/ckeditor5",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-countup": "^4.2.0",
    "react-data-grid": "^6.1.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.2",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.10.1",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.3",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.14",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^4.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-scroll-4": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
    "react-smart-data-table": "^0.7.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "react-star-rating-component": "^1.4.1",
    "react-switch": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table-6": "^6.11.0",
    "react-tabs": "^3.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.3.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "Faker": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

src/ckeditor5

[image]

node_modules

[image]

Comment: Have you come up with any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your package.json

Try Below code

```
 "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-tong": "{version of build tong}",
```

Instead of

```
 "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-tong": "file:./src/ckeditor5",
```